# PHP date converting to incorrect format

Tags: php

I am posting data with dates in this format:

```
06/11/2015
```

i then use the below function to change the date format to insert into a database:

```
ChangeDateFormat('06/11/2015', 'Y-m-d');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
if(!function_exists("ChangeDateFormat")) {
    function ChangeDateFormat($date = '', $format = '') {
        if($date == '' or $date == '0000-00-00' or $date == '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
            return '-';
        } else {
            return date($format, strtotime($date));
        }
    }
}
```

but its inserting into the following format:

`2015-06-11` whereas it should be `2015-11-06`

Comment: When using `strtotime()`, a date string containing `/` will be treated as US format (`m/d/Y`); A date string containing `-` will be treated as UK/European format (`d/m/Y`); as documented in the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: That's an american format but you're trying to use it as European. That won't work.

Comment: PHP tries to guess what date format was meant. This cannot always be correct, since that notation is vague. That is a huge problem with those old fashioned notations still in use in the anglophile world. Same issue with temperatures, times, weights, sizes, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible. [link](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)